# show location Swift3

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I'm trying to show my current location on simulator but it displays another location

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class DriverVC: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var myMap: MKMapView!
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var driverLocation : CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    var userLocation : CLLocationCoordinate2D?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        intializeLocationManager()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let location = locationManager.location?.coordinate {
            print("location\(location)")
            myMap.removeAnnotations(myMap.annotations)
            driverLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude)
            let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: driverLocation!, span: MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.07, 0.07))
            myMap.setRegion(region, animated: true)
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.coordinate = driverLocation!
            annotation.title = "driver location"
            myMap.addAnnotation(annotation)
        }
    }

    private func intializeLocationManager() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    @IBAction func signOut(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        if (AuthProvider.Instance.logOut()){
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else{
            alertTheUser(title: "couldn't sign out", message: "try again")
        }
    }

    @IBAction func answer(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }

    private func alertTheUser(title: String, message: String){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(ok)
        present(alert,animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I added Location when in usage description to Info.plist and the simulator debug location is non

Comment: Which location?

Comment: @Kerberos it displays a location in London and I'm not in it..how to display my current location?

Comment: The simulator can't get your *actual* location; It doesn't have GPS hardware.  You have to simulate a location from the menu.  You can use GPX files to add additional simulated locations

Comment: From simulator you can only simulate your position, you must use a real device to debug and test your code.